# How to delete a column from sheetjs with some condition using angular 4?

Tags: angular, xlsx, xlsxwriter, sheetjs

```
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    ws.set_column('Y1', None, None, {'hidden': True});

/* add to workbook */
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'content');

/* generate an XLSX file */
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'test.xlsx');
```

}

i am exporting the json object using angular 4 like this, its giving me expected results.

But when i am trying to hide a particular column

```
/* hide column*/
if (this.column === 'No') {
ws.set_column('A1', None, None, {'hidden': True});

}
```

Here in this code it is giving me error for `None`, `true` that can not find name none and true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sheetJs there is no such set_column() function.

If someone really delete some columns or rows can delete by `map`

ex:=

suppose you have your `response` in some variable called `resultResposne`

```
this.resultResponse.map((obj) =>{



 if(){ 

    // your condition goes here
       delete obj.`your column`;

    }

})
```